# entropy power inequality in information theory

Tags: information-theory

I'm studying lecture notes on "Diffusion equations and entropy inequalities"
http://mate.unipv.it/toscani/publi/Note-Ravello-2016.pdf

(1) The author asserts that (1.5)
$$
N(X+Z_t)\ge(1-t)N(X)+tN(X+Z_1), \quad 0\le t\le1.
$$
is stronger than (1.4)
$$
N(X+Y)\ge N(X)+N(Y).
$$

(2) (1.5) is equivalent to
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}N(X+Z_t)\le0
$$

I have looked for concave functions on wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function), but cannot see why the two facts are true. I Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: what is $N(X)$?

Comment: $N(X)=N(f)=e^{-\frac{2}{d}\int_{{R}^d} f\,\log f\,dx}$. The definition can be seen on page 5 of http://mate.unipv.it/toscani/publi/Note-Ravello-2016.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested in your question, you can take a look at the short paper [A short proof of the concavity of entropy power](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/07/016.EPI_.pdf) written by C. Villani